# How to make a part that changes your team in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make it so when you spawn in my Roblox Game, you are in a room. If you walk through one of the doors, it teleports you and changes your team. Here is my code so far:

```
function onTouched(m)
    p = m.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if p ~= nil then
        p.Torso.CFrame = CFrame.new(0,8,9) --Change to coordinates.
    end
end
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

I made it so it can teleport you, but I don't know how to make it so it also changes your team. Here are my teams

[image: Teams]

When you first join, you are on the Citizen team. When you walk through the door, you go to the Castle Team.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution without writing any code:**

Place 2 SpawnLocations in your initial room. 
Set properties of first SpawnLocation like this:

- AllowTeamChangeOnTouch: **true**
- Neutral: **false**
- TeamColor: **Red** (set this according to your team color)

Second SpawnLocation like this:

- AllowTeamChangeOnTouch: **true**
- Neutral: **false**
- TeamColor: **Blue** (set this according to your team color)

In your TEAMS folder in Explorer (Roblox Studio Explorer) set for both your teams "AutoAssignable" to **FALSE**.

Place these SpawnLocations just in front of your 2 doors, so the player MUST touch them (step on them) before he walks in the door.

**How it works**:

If a new player comes to the game, he will spawn in the center of your room, while he has no team assigned yet.

Then he must walk through one of your SpawnLocations, which assigns a team to him (depending which SpawnLocation he steps on).

Afterwards he can continue to the door.

Next time this player spawns into the game (after his death). He will spawn directly on the SpawnLocation of his team and can go directly into the door.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function 'GetPlayerFromCharacter' and then change the Player's team from there

```
function onTouched(m)
    p = m.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    if p ~= nil and p:FindFirstChild("Torso") then
        p.Torso.CFrame = CFrame.new(0,8,9) --Change to coordinates.

        if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(m.Parent) ~= nil then
            game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(m.Parent).Team = game.Teams["Castle Team"] --Change to desired team.
        end
    end
end
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

Edit: Taazar's script is better, please use that that instead of mine

Answer (score 0):

Before I start on the team changer you should note that changing the CFrame of a player's `"Torso"` will kill them. Instead you should change the CFrame of a part called `"HumanoidRootPart"` which is sorted in the character and has the same position as the player's `"Torso"`.

Another point is that when creating a new CFrame position with only the three co-ordinates you need to convert it from a Vector3. So following all that your teleport line will become:

```
p.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0,8,9))
```

Then for changing the teams I would look at Crabway's answer as I don't see any issues with the team changing part. Therefore your end result code will look something like this:

```
function onTouched(m)
    p = m.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    if p ~= nil and p:FindFirstChild("Torso") then
        p.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0,8,9)) --Change to coordinates.

        if game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(m.Parent) ~= nil then
            game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(m.Parent).Team = game.Teams["Castle Team"] --Change to desired team.
        end
    end
end
script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouched)
```

Comment: (Disclaimer: I don't have access to a RBX.Lua environment right now so there may be other issues with the code, if there are leave a comment and I will edit that answer accordingly.)